# Remove a Local Docker Image Tag Without Deleting the Image

Tags: docker

I'm new on the containers world and I recently have started with *Docker*. But I'm having some issues, and I couldn't find a solution ( at least one I understand minimally).
So, here's the problem:

- I want to **delete** a local image tag ("repository"/"tag" combination). Is it possible?
- How can I, having multiple TAGs associated with just one image ID, delete any of these TAGs without deleting the others? In my case, I just wanna to exclude the *hiworld* repository. I'm able to delete the image and therefore all the TAGs associated with, but this is not what I want to do. **Below** is what is displayed when I enter  the command *docker images*.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
helloworld1         latest              8916c2510f76        3 hours ago         148MB
hiworld             latest              8916c2510f76        3 hours ago         148MB
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of linking to a *picture* of a few lines of text, just include the actual text here in your question.

Comment: okok, will do this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`docker rmi` (the *remove image* command) does this.

```
$ docker rmi hiworld:latest
```

That will *untag* `hiworld:latest`, but will leave `helloworld1:latest` (and `8916c2510f76`) in place. According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/),

> If an image has one or more tags referencing it, you must remove all of them before the image is removed.